# Copying a range using Combo Box criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I'm trying to copy a range that meets two criteria from two combo boxes on a user form.

ComboBox1 contains criteria 1, the Branch.
ComboBox2 contains criteria 2, the Quarter.

Column `A` needs to match the Branch criteria and Row `1` needs to match the Quarter criteria.

[image: Image of Range]

I cannot get my code to work properly. It only copies data from column `2` and is not checking the entire row for the Quarters criteria.

For example, if I select the Pearl branch and quarter Q1 the code should copy "apple" and "8".

Here is the code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long, ws2 As Worksheet

With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To LastRow

        If .Cells(i, 1) = ComboBox1 And .Cells(1, 2) = ComboBox2 Then
            With Worksheets("Sheet4")
                .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = _
                     Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 2).Value
            End With
        End If

    Next i
End With
Unload Me

End Sub
```

Comment: Much better version of the question than the previous one! You could have just edited it instead of creating a new one, though.

Comment: @JoseCortez,, do you have data in two different Sheets,, Sht 1 & 4 or in one Sheet only Since I found `With Worksheets("Sheet1")` & down to lines is, `With Worksheets("Sheet4")` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem with your code is that though you are correctly looping through the rows, you aren't looping through the columns.

Adding an inner loop would solve this. However, a better solution is to use the worksheet function `MATCH()` to find the matching row, and loop through the *columns* instead:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim LastColumn As Long
Dim i As Long

With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    LastColumn = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Dim lngMatchingRow As Long
    lngMatchingRow = Excel.WorksheetFunction.Match(ComboBox1.Value, .Range("A:A"), 0)

    For i = 2 To LastColumn

        If .Cells(1, i).Value2 = ComboBox2.Value Then
            With Worksheets("Sheet4")
                .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = _
                     Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(lngMatchingRow, i).Value2
            End With
        End If

    Next i
End With
Unload Me

End Sub
```

Note that I've taken the liberty of modifying some other parts of the code to follow best practices:

- Variables should be declared one per line
- Variables should be declared as close to first usage as possible
- `.Value2` show always be used in preference to `.Value` when pulling data from a spreadsheet
- Instead of relying on default properties, they should be explicitly specified, e.g. `ComboBox1.Value` instead of `ComboBox1`

---

Now, if I were writing the code from scratch and if the Quarters were guaranteed to be grouped together, I would dispense with the column loop as well.

Instead, I would use `MATCH()` and `COUNTIF()` to find the column limits and copy the data all at once:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
        Dim ƒ As Excel.WorksheetFunction: Set ƒ = Excel.WorksheetFunction

  With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Dim lngMatchingRow As Long
    lngMatchingRow = ƒ.Match(ComboBox1.Value, .Range("A:A"), 0)
    Dim lngStartCol As Long
    lngStartCol = ƒ.Match(ComboBox2.Value, .Range("1:1"), 0)
    Dim lngColCount As Long
    lngColCount = ƒ.CountIf(.Range("1:1"), "Q1")

    Worksheets("Sheet4").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(lngColCount) _
    = ƒ.Transpose(.Cells(lngMatchingRow, lngStartCol).Resize(1, lngColCount).Value2)

  End With
  Unload Me

End Sub
```

Comment: excellent! your code does exactly what I needed it to do. Thank you!!

Comment: @JoseCortez You're welcome :) Don't forget, now that you have 15+ reputation, you can upvote any answer (or question), including an answer you have accepted ;-)

Comment: @JoseCortez I've added a non-loop version of the code, if you're interested.

Comment: is there a way to loop through the data by rows? I uploaded an image of what I am trying to do. If ComboBox1 is "Sample 1" and ComboBox 2 is "Q1" then it should copy 12,150 & 10,750. Your first solution worked, but i am splitting my data up differently now. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @JoseCortez Yes. As explained at the start of my answer, adding an inner loop would work, and in fact is essential if there are multiple possible matching rows as well as columns. Using my first code, for example, the simplest solution would be to loop through all the rows once a matching column is found. A faster, more advanced technique would be to use `MATCH()` starting at the row below the previous match in order to find the next match. § That being said, this really belongs in a new question, not as an edit to the current one (which I have reverted). Make an attempt at a solution, and …

Comment: … if you get stuck, post a new question. You can ping me to let me know that you have done so by posting a comment here. Make sure that the question clearly describes what data you are attempting to extract: Is it always from the `Cons Load Actual` column? Are all the quarters stacked vertically? (Show an example sheet containing `Q1` values *and* `Q2` values.) If the answers are both yes, then a single loop using `MATCH()` to find the next Quarter, and the another `MATCH()` to find the appropriate Branch would be the best solution.